# Show/hide not working in IE8 - JQUERY

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have tried looking at other questions similar to mine but none of them help me.

I have some multiple divs that I need to show and hide one by one when the user clicks on an input. My code works well in all browsers except for IE8, where nothing happens in other words the divs do not show.
Please can someone help me with this problem?

here is my HTML

```
<div id="tabbedBox">
                    <form action="" method="">
                        <div class="tabbed" id="selectMe">
                            <input type="radio" target="1" id="pvl" name="radios" value="a" checked>
                            <label class="pvl"  for="pvl">PVL</label>
                            <input type="radio" target="2" id="cvl" name="radios" value="b">
                            <label class="cvl" for="cvl">CVL</label>
                            <input type="radio" target="3" id="industrial" name="radios" value="c">
                            <label class="industrial" for="industrial">Industrial</label>
                            <input type="radio" target="4" id="distributor" name="radios" value="d">
                            <label class="distributor" for="distributor">Distributor</label>
                        </div>





                        <div class="pvlBox tabbedContent" id="div1">
                            <div class="select">
                                <input type="radio" id="installed" name="radios" value="" checked>
                                <label for="installed">Installed</label>
                            </div>
                            <span>Installed</span>
                            <div class="select">
                                <input type="radio" id="retail" name="radios" value="">
                                <label for="retail">Retail</label>
                            </div>
                            <span>Retail</span>
                            <div class="select">
                                <input type="radio" id="service" name="radios" value="">
                                <label for="service">Service Station</label>
                            </div>
                            <span>Service Station</span>
                        </div>

                            <div class="cvlBox tabbedContent" id="div2" style="display:none">
                                CVL CONTENT
                            <div class="select">
                                <input type="radio" id="installed" name="radios" value="" checked>
                                <label for="installed">Installed</label>
                            </div>
                            <span>Installed</span>
                            <div class="select">
                                <input type="radio" id="retail" name="radios" value="">
                                <label for="retail">Retail</label>
                            </div>
                            <span>Retail</span>
                            <div class="select">
                                <input type="radio" id="service" name="radios" value="">
                                <label for="service">Service Station</label>
                            </div>
                            <span>Service Station</span>
                        </div>
                            <div class="industrialBox tabbedContent" id="div3"  style="display:none">
                                INDUSTRIAL CONTENT
                            <div class="select">
                                <input type="radio" id="installed" name="radios" value="" checked>
                                <label for="installed">Installed</label>
                            </div>
                            <span>Installed</span>
                            <div class="select">
                                <input type="radio" id="retail" name="radios" value="">
                                <label for="retail">Retail</label>
                            </div>
                            <span>Retail</span>
                            <div class="select">
                                <input type="radio" id="service" name="radios" value="">
                                <label for="service">Service Station</label>
                            </div>
                            <span>Service Station</span>
                        </div>

                            <div class="distributorBox tabbedContent" id="div4"  style="display:none">
                                DISTRIBUTOR CONTENT
                            <div class="select">
                                <input type="radio" id="installed" name="radios" value="" checked>
                                <label for="installed">Installed</label>
                            </div>
                            <span>Installed</span>
                            <div class="select">
                                <input type="radio" id="retail" name="radios" value="">
                                <label for="retail">Retail</label>
                            </div>
                            <span>Retail</span>
                            <div class="select">
                                <input type="radio" id="service" name="radios" value="">
                                <label for="service">Service Station</label>
                            </div>
                            <span>Service Station</span>
                        </div>

                        <br/>


                    </form>
            </div><!--/end tabbedbox-->
```

Here is the jquery code:

```
$('#pvl').click(function() {
        $('div[id^=div]').hide();
        $('#div1').show();

    });
    $('#cvl').click(function() {
        $('div[id^=div]').hide();
        $('#div2').show();
    });

    $('#industrial').click(function() {
        $('div[id^=div]').hide();
        $('#div3').show();
    });

    $('#distributor').click(function() {
        $('div[id^=div]').hide();
        $('#div4').show();
    });

});
```

Comment: What version of jquery are you using, jquery 2.x does not support IE 8

Comment: Oh really, I am using the latest version. Which version should I use, Esa?

Comment: Use version 1.x, see here http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: No luck, it did not work :(, and there are no errors in the console to give me any clues either. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm unable to get the code working in fiddle, i'll try to see whats wrong.

Comment: It is in a ready function yes

Comment: I guess you're missing quotes around 'div" in your selector.hide... I think it should be $('div[id^="div" '].hide(). (double quotes around 'starts with "div"'

Comment: I tried that Phron but still nothing... very frustrating

Comment: I got it working in this fiddle..http://jsfiddle.net/9geN2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v added a little more markup to simplify the script. Also changed the click event to change-event:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RJSg7/)

Script:

```
$(function () {
    $(".js-change").on("change", function () {
        $(".Box").hide();
        $("." + $(this).data("show-content")).show();
    });
});
```

Html (added classes and data-attributes to radiobuttons):

```
<div id="tabbedBox">
    <form action="" method="">
        <div class="tabbed" id="selectMe">
            <input type="radio" target="1" id="pvl" name="radios" value="a" 
                  class="js-change" data-show-content="pvlBox" checked>
            <label class="pvl" for="pvl">PVL</label>
            <input type="radio" target="2" id="cvl" name="radios" value="b" 
                  class="js-change" data-show-content="cvlBox">
            <label class="cvl" for="cvl">CVL</label>
            <input type="radio" target="3" id="industrial" name="radios" value="c"
                  class="js-change" data-show-content="industrialBox">
            <label class="industrial" for="industrial">Industrial</label>
            <input type="radio" target="4" id="distributor" name="radios" value="d"
                  class="js-change" data-show-content="distributorBox">
            <label class="distributor" for="distributor">Distributor</label>
        </div>
        <div class="Box pvlBox tabbedContent">
            <div class="select">
                <input type="radio" id="installed" name="radios" value="" checked>
                <label for="installed">Installed</label>
            </div> <span>Installed</span>

            <div class="select">
                <input type="radio" id="retail" name="radios" value="">
                <label for="retail">Retail</label>
            </div> <span>Retail</span>

            <div class="select">
                <input type="radio" id="service" name="radios" value="">
                <label for="service">Service Station</label>
            </div> <span>Service Station</span>

        </div>
        <div class="Box cvlBox tabbedContent" style="display:none">CVL CONTENT
            <div class="select">
                <input type="radio" id="installed" name="radios" value="" checked>
                <label for="installed">Installed</label>
            </div> <span>Installed</span>

            <div class="select">
                <input type="radio" id="retail" name="radios" value="">
                <label for="retail">Retail</label>
            </div> <span>Retail</span>

            <div class="select">
                <input type="radio" id="service" name="radios" value="">
                <label for="service">Service Station</label>
            </div> <span>Service Station</span>

        </div>
        <div class="Box industrialBox tabbedContent" style="display:none">INDUSTRIAL CONTENT
            <div class="select">
                <input type="radio" id="installed" name="radios" value="" checked>
                <label for="installed">Installed</label>
            </div> <span>Installed</span>

            <div class="select">
                <input type="radio" id="retail" name="radios" value="">
                <label for="retail">Retail</label>
            </div> <span>Retail</span>

            <div class="select">
                <input type="radio" id="service" name="radios" value="">
                <label for="service">Service Station</label>
            </div> <span>Service Station</span>

        </div>
        <div class="Box distributorBox tabbedContent" id="div4" style="display:none">DISTRIBUTOR CONTENT
            <div class="select">
                <input type="radio" id="installed" name="radios" value="" checked>
                <label for="installed">Installed</label>
            </div> <span>Installed</span>

            <div class="select">
                <input type="radio" id="retail" name="radios" value="">
                <label for="retail">Retail</label>
            </div> <span>Retail</span>

            <div class="select">
                <input type="radio" id="service" name="radios" value="">
                <label for="service">Service Station</label>
            </div> <span>Service Station</span>

        </div>
        <br/>
    </form>
</div>
<!--/end tabbedbox-->
```

Comment: Thank you Esa, turns out the change event was a problem and i chnaged the selector which solved the problem...

Comment: $(function () {
    $("#selectMe label").click(function () {
        $(".tabbedContent").hide();
        $("." + $(this).prev().data("show-content")).show();
    });
});